# "That" vs "Those" which to use after both a plural and a singular noun?

Tags: grammar, agreement

"The rise of computer technologies and networking is due to collective action similar to that of other social movements, such as the environmental movement, the anti-tobacco movement or the women's movement, for example."

1. In terms of traditional grammar, is it technically wrong to say "those" instead of "that"? 2. If so, is it still wrong even in colloquial situations?
2. Are there other errors or slight incoherency from the viewpoint of a native speaker?
   FYI since I'm not a native, I would very much like a response from a fluent native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, it is technically wrong to say **those**. However, many people will prefer **those** to **that** because it seems to agree with 'other social movements'. But in your sentence, the word **that** agrees with **collective action** as it should.

In colloquial situations, either will probably go by unnoticed.

For your second question, the combination of **such as** and **for example** is redundant. If I were you, I would leave the **such as** in and take out **for example**. I'd also stick in an oxford comma after **anti-tobacco movement**, but that's a matter of preference.

Comment: For the benefit of those in Commonwealth countries, I would like to add that nearly all British style manuals oppose the use of the "Oxford comma" unless absolutely necessary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma#Mainly_British_style_guides_opposing_mandatory_use

Answer (score 0):

"is due to" is not good English (though commonly used). A better phrase would be one which makes it perfectly clear what logical connection you are making between "the rise of X and Y" and "collective action". Do you mean "is produced by"?

Comment: What makes you say that "'is due to' is not good English"? It sounds perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

"The rise of computer technologies and networking is due to collective action similar to that of other social movements, such as the environmental movement, the anti-tobacco movement or the women's movement, for example."

All things considered, if I didn't misunderstand the context, you can fix multiple parts. This is how I read it after rereading thrice.

"**Computer-related** technologies **arose** from collective **actions** similar to **those** in other social movements."

This emphasizes the main point of the sentence, the commonness and effectiveness of collective action.

Because of the reasons included in this sentence:

"**Computer-related** (because computer technologies technically includes a wide variety of fields) technologies, including networking, (probably this "including networking" idea can be cut) **arose from** (from "rise" in the previous sentence) collective **actions** (because one action didn't cause the entirety of the multiple computer-related technologies to develop) similar to **those** (there are multiple social movements, so it must be plural instead of a singular pronoun) other social movements (the examples of the other social movement is particularly irrelevant to the sentence's main idea of a commonness and effectiveness of collective action)."